# Verify a proof: Alternating operator applied on a 3-linear function gives 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra

I feel like I'm messing something up badly in the proof but I'm not able to see it, so I'm writing the proof down in hopes that someone catches an error:

Let $f$ be a $3$ linear function,  $f: V^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Define the alternating operator $A$, which converts any $3$-linear map into an alternating $3$-linear map.

$$
A :  (V^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow (V^3 \rightarrow \mathbb {R}) \\
A(f) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} \text{sgn}(\sigma) (\sigma f)
$$ where $S_k$ is the symmetric group on $k$ letters, and $\sigma f$ is the action of $\sigma$ on the inputs of $f$. 
That is,
$$(\sigma f) (x_1, x_2, x_3) \equiv
f(x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)}, x_{\sigma(3)})
$$

We are now asked to compute $A(f)$ for any $f : V^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  $f$ multilinear.

#### Proof

Let us evaluate $A(f)$ on some $(x, y, z)$.

\begin{align}
A(&f)(x, y, z) = \\
&f(x, y, z) + \\
-&f (x, z, y) + \\
-&f(z, y, x) + \\
-&f(y, x, z) + \\
&f(z, y, x) + \\
&f(y, z, x)
\end{align}

Which on using the linearity of $f$ yields:
$$A(f) = f(0, 0, 0)$$

(Notice that the signs on the $x$ and $-x$ cancel out, as do for $y$ and $z$)

Is this proof correct? If so, what is the intuition for this? Why is only the "degenerate" solution popping up? Is it something to do with the odd dimension of the vector space? (dim = 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linearity holds for one entry only when other entries are unchanged. 
$$A(f)(x, y, z) = f(x, y, z) + f(y, z, x) + f(z, x, y) - f(x, z, y) - f(y, x, z) -f(z, y, x)$$

None of these will cancel each other if we only assume $f$ is 3-linear. However, if we assume f is symmetric we will get 0.

Comment: Ahh, yes, thank you! That's what I was missing :) 

Could you motivate this definition of multi-llinearity versus "my" definition $g(x, y) + g(a, b) = g(x + a, y + b)$?

If we assume $f$ is symmetric, we can rearrange all the function to $f(x, y, z)$ and then it'll all cancel to give $0$, correct?

Comment: Take a look at the typical example of n-linear function: determinant. It is multilinear w.r.t. each column, and the geometric meaning of it is just the volume of a n-cuboid whose volume is $V$. Multiply one column by a constant $\lambda_1$ and the n-cuboid is stretched to $\lambda_1$ its length in that direction, and the volume is $\lambda_1V$. But multiply another column by $\lambda_2$, the volume will be $\lambda_1\lambda_2V$ rather than $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)V$. This is probably where the people who define multilinearity starts.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat: "your" definition already has a name - linearity!